# Problems in getting data from CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, nsstream

I'm building an iPhoe app with a socket to a PC app , I need to get an image from this PC app.
It's my first time using "CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost".After I establish the socket with "NSOperation" I call

```
CFStreamClientContext streamContext = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
BOOL success = CFReadStreamSetClient(myReadStream, kMyNetworkEvents,MyStreamCallBack,&streamContext);
CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(myReadStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

then I call

```
CFWriteStreamWrite(myWriteStream, &writeBuffer, 3);
// Open read stream.
 if (!CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream)) {
  // Notify error
 }
.
.
.
while(!cancelled && !finished) {
  SInt32 result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.25, NO);
```

if (result == kCFRunLoopRunStopped || result == kCFRunLoopRunFinished) {
   break;
  }

if (([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - _lastRead) > MyConnectionTimeout) {
   // Call timed out
   cancelled = YES;

break;
  }

// Also handle stream status 
  CFStreamStatus status = CFReadStreamGetStatus(myReadStream);
 }

and then when I get "kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable"
I use

```
while (CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable(myReadStream))
{
   CFReadStreamRead(myReadStream, readBuffer, 1000);
//and buffer the the bytes
}
```

It's unpredictable , sometimes I get the whole picture , sometime I got just part of it , and I can't understand what make the different.
can someone has an idea what is wrong here?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you get `kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable`, it's possible that only *some* of the bytes are available and the remaining bytes won't arrive until later.

Imagine you are expecting a total of 5,000 bytes.

Because of unpredictable network timings, this is one scenario:

1. Two packets, each containing 1,000 bytes, arrive almost immediately.
2. Your callback is invoked with `kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` because there are 2,000 bytes waiting.
3. You're code loops though the `while` loop twice, consuming 1,000 bytes each time.
4. The `while` loop exits because the `CFReadStream` has no more bytes available. **Does your code recognize that you don't yet have all your data even though there aren't currently any more bytes waiting?**
5. Another packet, containing 1,000 bytes, arrives.
6. Your callback is invoked *again* with `kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` because there are 1,000 more bytes waiting. **Are you prepared for this second callback?**
7. Steps 5 & 6 occur twice more.